# Issue While Sending Automatic Emails Odoo

Tags: email, odoo

I am having problems while sending automatic mails in Odoo 8. I have made an automated action consisting of an email template having a successfully tested outgoing mail server. Now the 'Email Queue Manager' defined in Scheduled Actions should send the mail on the 'Trigger Date' defined in Automated Action.But im not getting any mail. I am unable to find my mistake. Plz give me some guidance on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this step:

1). My  Outgoing Mail Servers test is successful

2). I have set time to UTC in server and in Odoo Timezone to Asia\kolkata or Your Timezone set.

3). I have been able to  auto generate mail using a Automated action to email queue with recipients as some name on create and update in the module
4). I can send mails from queue manually by selecting.

you changed the interval for the 'Email Queue Manager' **under Settings > Automation > Scheduled Actions**
which would mean that e-mails are still in the waiting list until the date is passed that is set on our Queue manager.

By default changing the internal only works from the first time the next date is passed. If your old interval was a week it will not even before next week. So also set 'Next Execution Date' on today and about 5 mins. from now!

and Verify how many you have a running server instances. Stop server, kill all other instances, start server.

Comment: when i set the condition 'When To Run' as 'On Update', I get the mails but setting it as 'Based On Time Condition'. Its not sending any mail on 'Trigger Date'